# Como configurar a ação do botão voltar no android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como executar determinadas atividades no app quando o botão voltar for ouvido?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Olá amigo!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    //Seu código aqui dentro
}
```